# your project contains errors Eclipse Red Exclamation Mark At Project

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling

When I want to run an application window in eclipse saying my project contains errors pops out. Although there are no red crosses on the project files. What could cause this?

Comment: Did you check all the files? There can be an error in the manifest, strings.xml, layout or drawable files

Comment: there are no red marks at none of the folders or files in the project for sure

Comment: Open the Problems view (Window > Show View > Problems). That should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Also, is there anything in the log?

Comment: Open the 'problems' tab on the bottom of the IDE (near LogCat)

Comment: Sometimes it's a **false positive** given by old (solved) errors still persisting in the `Problems` and/or the `Error Log` windows. Clear the contents of these windows and re run.

Comment: there are problems in different projects but not this one.

Comment: Have you tried as other's have said, clean the project and then restart Eclipse?

Comment: now there is red exclamation mark on the project folder.

Comment: I cleaned the project and restarted app. Also, I removed projects with errors as I didn't need them.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the problem by fixing the Build Path. There was a problem.

Comment: it sometimes happen. you just refresh your workspace or  build project.

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue many times and i solved it by just **refresh** my workspace or  **build** project with **Ctrl + B** .